# Nicolas Bourbaki - Why is a theorem R equivalent to "For any x then R"

Tags: set-theory

In the Theory of Sets I've found the following paragraph:

> Let $R$ be a relation in $\mathscr{C}$. By C26, C27, and C30 it is the same (provided the letter $x$ is not a constant of $\mathscr{C}$) whether we state the theorem R in $\mathscr{C}$, or the theorem $(\forall x)R$, or the metamathematical rule: if T is any term in $\mathscr{C}$, then $(T|x)R$ is a theorem in $\mathscr{C}$.

I understand from it that if you have $R$ you are sure to have $(\forall x) R$, but I can't figure out why if you have a theorem $(\forall x) R$ in your theory you should also be able to prove R.

C26 is:

> Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a logical theory, let $R$ be a relation in $\mathscr{C}$, and let $x$ be a letter. The relations $(\forall x)R$ and $(\tau_x(\neg R)|x)R$ are then equivalent in $\mathscr{C}$.

C27 is:

> If $R$ is a theorem in a logical theory $\mathscr{C}$ in which the letter $x$ is not a constant, then $(\forall x)R$ is a theorem in $\mathscr{C}$.

c30 is:

> Let $R$ be a relation in $\mathscr{C}$, let $T$ be a term in $\mathscr{C}$, and let $x$ be a letter. Then the relation $(\forall x)R \implies (T|x)R$ is a theorem in $\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: "$x$" is letter, so term, so you can use in $c30$ $(x|x)R$.

Comment: Hmm, I guess because I didn't see any example of (x|x)R it didn't occur to me that it would be the same as R (I guess it was obvious). I'm still having trouble with the part "if T is any term of ...", even if that was not my original question.

Comment: Apparently your deductive system allows theorems (and terms) to include free variables so that outermost "forall"s are effectively redundant. Many systems don't work like that, but it's a technical detail that shouldn't have deep implications.

Comment: @Karl. I understand your idea, but there are no definition for free or bound variables in mentioned book before debated issue. So, in answers and comments I prefer to stay within the framework of the monograph under discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me write answers to both questions here. To prove 3d sentence let assume, for example, that $(\forall x)R$ is theorem in $\mathscr{C}$. As $(x|x)R$ is identical to $R$, then we can use $C30$ and have, that $(\forall x)R\Rightarrow R$ is theorem, so $R$ is theorem.

Now about your question in comment: we can start with that $R$ is theorem and use $C3$ from "3. SUBSTITUTIONS IN A THEORY, $§$ 2. Theorems"(in my 2004 edition it is on page 26). This gives  $(T|x)R$ is theorem.